# Switch form paragraph mode to line break mode in WYSIWYG editor because of client request?

Tags: text-editor, client-relations, formatting

I'm building a website fro a client which uses TinyMCE as the main WYSIWYG editor. Now my client asked if it is possible to write a line and make a line break and then continue without leaving  a space between the text before and after the line break (e.g. just like in word).

I told him that the web uses paragraph for formatting and not line breaks. Still he'd like to use line breaks for formatting. Should I convince him not to use line breaks for formatting or should I just switch TinyMCE to line break mode ([which the is not recommended in the TinyMCE documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_produce_P_elements_on_enter.2Freturn_instead_of_BR_elements.3F)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `<br />` tag wherever you want a new line...

If tinyMCE doesn't have a button for that already, I remember it was dead simple to write plugins like that with a few lines of javascript.

Same as on SE, you can use it like this:

This should work `<br />`with no problems.

This should work 
with no problems.

Comment: What do you mean by SE?

Comment: this site (or network of Q&A sites), SE = StackExchange

Comment: See. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the CSS for `<p>` tags for the areas of the site you are concerned with so that they have no margin or padding?

```
.mycontent p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```